# How to add css to jquery backstretch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-backstretch

So I was able to create a slideshow using the jquery backstretch.

```
     $.backstretch([
      'assets/images/main-01.jpg'
    , 'assets/images/main-02.jpg'
    , 'assets/images/main-03.jpg'
  ], {duration: 5000, fade: 850});
```

However, I wish to add a `repeating-linear-gradient` effect on the images

```
background-image:repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, transparent 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px);
```

Is it possible to apply the above css to the backstretch images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes it is possible.**
You just need an overlay for the backstretch images:

```
#backstretch-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
        0deg, 
        transparent, 
        transparent
        2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px
    );
}
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFJs9/146/) I attached backstretch to a container to have some control over it, but that is not particularly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can see me demo:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
    background-image: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/garfield-interior.jpg');
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/gFJs9/144/)

or

You just have to Include the jQuery library (version 1.7 or newer) and Backstretch plugin files in your webpage, preferably at the bottom of the page, before the closing `` `tag`.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // To attach Backstrech as the body's background
  $.backstretch("path/to/image.jpg");

  // You may also attach Backstretch to a block-level element
  $(".foo").backstretch("path/to/image.jpg");

  // Or, to start a slideshow, just pass in an array of images
  $(".foo").backstretch([
    "path/to/image.jpg",
    "path/to/image2.jpg",
    "path/to/image3.jpg"    
  ], {duration: 4000});
</script>
```